# Currency switcher remove redirect

Tags: magento-1.9

```
http://stage.infinitealoe.com/directory/currency/switch/currency/CAD/uenc/aHR0cDovL3N0YWdlLmluZmluaXRlYWxvZS5jb20,?___store=default
```

I am getting above Currency switcher redirect url. How can i remove it?

Comment: I think you need to disable `Add Store Code to Urls` from magento admin

Comment: What do you want to remove?

Comment: i already disabled Add Store Code to Urls

Comment: When my page loads i get this in gtmetrix Avoid landing page redirects from there i need to remove

Comment: I could not get `?___store=default` in URL, it is working fine for me.

Comment: I'm guessing this is related to this question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240041/magento1-site-mobile-friendly-test-error

your currency converter is only redirecting google bot.  Are you using a 3rd party extension to redirect based on ip or user agent?

Comment: yes it is related to that.